# Update all references to an object when the object is updated(reference to a reference)

Tags: java, object, pointers, reference

I want to declare an object in java that is like a a pointer to a pointer in C++, let me show you an example :

```
//*** At the application startup

//Initialize a settings container class
Settings settings = //Load settings 

//Declaring static Application class that contain a reference to the settings container
Application.setSettings(settings);

//Get sub settings from settings container class
DatabaseSettings dbSettings =  settings.getDbSettings();
LogSettings logSettings = settings.getLogSettings();

//Initialize components 
DatabaseConnector dbConn = new DatabaseConnector(dbSettings);
Logger logger = new Logger(logSettings);
```

In the above code i have created a settings container class that contain all settings of my application components, then i have assigned each sub settings class to the related component, at this point during the execution of the program i want to update the settings and let the component of the application to see the updated settings, so for example during the execution i can update the settings container in this way :

```
//Update settings through Application static class 
Settings newSettings = //assign updated settings
Application.setSettings(newSettings);
```

Now the problem is that when i update the settings container at runtime the application static class will contain the updated reference to the `newSettings` instance while each sub Settings instance keep referencing the old sub settings, so :

```
dbConn      ---> settings.getDbSettings()
logSettings ---> settings.getLogSettings()
```

While i want that the two reference automatically reference to the new instance of the settings, so :

```
dbConn      ---> newSettings.getDbSettings()
logSettings ---> newSettings.getLogSettings()
```

It is like a pointer to pointer ... Is it possible in Java ? How can it be done ?

Comment: If you pass the same object it will reference the same object in memory, effectively it is a pointer.

Comment: What you can do is use a singleton pattern to ensure you use the one setting object, or an observer pattern to update the observers to your observable (the settings class)

Comment: Even the singleton pattern isn't guaranteed to work, it depends on what the constructor of DatabaseConnector and Logger do. If they copy the fields from the config, then even if you update the config those objects will never see a change. In that case the only option is the observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you only have references to objects.  To have a reference to a reference you need some sort of indirection. e.g.

```
AtomicReference<DatabaseSettings> refDatabaseSettings = new AtomicReference<DatabaseSettings>();

refDatabaseSettings.set(dbSettings);

DatabaseSettings dbSettings = refDatabaseSettings.get();
```

You can pass the ref around and change it in one place.  However, this won't notify any of the references that it has changed, just allow all references to see the same thing when they check next time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, instead of setting new settings in Application, update the existing ones.

Or simply document the fact that these settings could change, and that any code interested in having the new settings must always go through `Application.getSettings()`.

Comment: +1 The first statement is what I was going to write as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some form of notification system to accomplish what you are trying to do.  An observer/observable or some event based system with listeners that are interested in the changes is really the only way to go.

You could certainly create threadsafe settings objects (like DatabaseSettings) that can be updated, and therefore the consumer of the object will get the new values, but this will only work in the simplest of cases.  The problem with this approach is that the results of multiple calls to the settings instance will become inconsistent.  Assuming that there are multiple settings in the settings object that are related to one another, if one settings is retrieved, the object is updated, and then the next setting is retrieved, you have no way of knowing that the two calls have produced inconsistent (to each other) values.

For Example:

```
dbSettings.getConnectionUrl();
dbSettings.getUsername();
```

If dbSettings is updated between these 2 calls, then the username and connection will no longer match.

The other issue is that if anyone extracts specific values from a settings object and stores them in another variable or class, they will have no way of knowing that it changed.

It makes the way in which these classes are used very rigid and error prone.