# Java: update object reference globally

Tags: java, object, pointers, reference

I want to update a reference to an object globally (nearly the same question as [Update all references to an object when the object is updated(reference to a reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882406/update-all-references-to-an-object-when-the-object-is-updatedreference-to-a-ref)).

I have the following code structure:

```java
class Triangle {
    Vertex pos[];
    //...
}

ArrayList<Vertex> vertices;

ArrayList<Triangle> triangles;

// Load triangles from file. After all triangles are loaded,
// fill the vertices list with all vertices of all triangles.
```

As you can see in the code example, first triangles are loaded. Some of my additional algorithms only need the list of all vertices. So to improve performance all vertices of all triangles are inserted in the vertices list and the algorithm only gets the list.

So lets say I have triangle `T1(a,b,c)`, `T2(d,e,f)` and `T3(e,g,h)`.
Vertices contains then `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`.

In one algorithm I need to replace a vertex with another one. For example `e` gets deleted and replaced with `a`.

Normally you would do this with the following code to get the updated Triangles `T1(a,b,c)`, `T2(d,a,f)` and `T3(a,g,h)`:

```
for (Triangle t : triangles) {
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (t.pos[i] == e)
            t.pos[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Is there another way to efficiently update all references which are pointing to `e`, so that the new target of the reference is `a`.
For example instead of using the loop and iterating over all triangles (which is not so efficient) a call like this would be useful:

```
Java.updateReferences(e,a);
```

Thanks

Comment: see the [Observer-Observable](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0175.shtml) pattern

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the vertex class should simply be mutable, and you should just change its coordinates:

```
e.setCoordinates(a.getCoordinates());
```

This way, all the references to e get the new coordinates automatically. If this is not an option, maybe you should just wrap the Vertex object into a `MutableVertex` object, and make the triangle objects and the vertices list contain instances of `MutableVertex`.

Comment: The vertex can't be mutable because it holds some other information, e.g. its normal vector. This gets calculated AFTER replacing. So with your first suggestion the algorithm needs to calculate the normal for two vectors which are the same.

Using MutableVertex could be an option, but this would require to update the already existing code (which is quite a lot)

Comment: There's not going to be a way to do this that doesn't involve a significant rewrite of your code.  You just can't do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a 'smart' List implmentation that looks for the vertices on the fly. For example, it could have

> int size() { return triangles.size() * 3; }
>
> Vertex get(int i) {return triangles.get( i / 3 ).getVertex(i % 3); }

or something along the lines of that. Consider extending java.util.AbstractList.

Comment: This wouldn't work because the vertices list hasn't exactly the length `triangles * 3` because some of the vertices are shared between triangles. So the algorithm which relies on the vertices list analyzes more vertices than needed.